# KeyedProcessFunction implementation throwing null pointer exception?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

First Example: code from "https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html"

I am trying to override processElement() of KeyedProcessFunction class. ProcessElement has 3 parameters and one of a parameter is context object. When I tried to retrieve timestamp from context object, it throws null pointer exception.

A line which throws null pointer exception in First example code is

current.lastModified = ctx.timestamp();

Second Example: Example 6.5 of "Stream Processing with Apache Flink" book.

I have two ValueState variables declared in a class which extends KeyedProcessFunction class. When I tried to retrieve the last value updated in the state, it returns a null value.

A line which throws null pointer exception in First example code is

Double prevTemp = lastTemp.value();
if(prevTemp==0.0 || r.temperature < prevTemp) {}

First Example code

```
public class KeyedProcessFunctionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment environment=
                StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        environment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> stream =
                environment.socketTextStream("localhost",9090)
                        .map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Tuple2<String, String> map(String s) throws Exception {
                                String[] words= s.split(",");

                                return new Tuple2<>(words[0],words[1]);
                            }
                        });

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> result = stream
                .keyBy(0)
                .process(new CountWithTimeoutFunction());

        result.print();

        environment.execute("Keyed Process Function Example");

    }
    public static class CountWithTimeoutFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<Tuple, Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<String, Long>> {
        private ValueState<CountWithTimestamp> state;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            state = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("myState", CountWithTimestamp.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(
                Tuple2<String, String> value,
                Context ctx,
                Collector<Tuple2<String, Long>> out) throws Exception {

            // retrieve the current count
            CountWithTimestamp current = state.value();
            if (current == null) {
                current = new CountWithTimestamp();
                current.key = value.f0;
            }

            // update the state's count
            current.count++;

            // set the state's timestamp to the record's assigned event time timestamp
            current.lastModified = ctx.timestamp();

            // write the state back
            state.update(current);

            // schedule the next timer 60 seconds from the current event time
            ctx.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(current.lastModified + 60000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimer(
                long timestamp,
                OnTimerContext ctx,
                Collector<Tuple2<String, Long>> out) throws Exception {

            // get the state for the key that scheduled the timer
            CountWithTimestamp result = state.value();

            // check if this is an outdated timer or the latest timer
            if (timestamp == result.lastModified + 60000) {
                // emit the state on timeout
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Long>(result.key, result.count));
            }
        }
    }
}

class CountWithTimestamp {

    public String key;
    public long count;
    public long lastModified;
}
```

Second Example

```
public class KeyedProcessFunctionTimerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // set up the streaming execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // use event time for the application
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);

        DataStream<String> sensorData=
                env.addSource(new SensorSource())
                .keyBy(r -> r.id)
                .process(new TempIncreaseAlertFunction());

        sensorData.print();
        env.execute("Keyed Process Function execution");
    }

    public static class TempIncreaseAlertFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, SensorReading, String> {

        private ValueState<Double> lastTemp;
        private ValueState<Long> currentTimer;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            lastTemp = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<Double>("lastTemp", Types.DOUBLE));
            currentTimer = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<Long>("timer", org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types.LONG));
        }

        @Override
        public void processElement(
                SensorReading r,
                Context ctx,
                Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

            // get previous Temp
            Double prevTemp = lastTemp.value();

            // update last temp
            lastTemp.update(r.temperature);

            Long curTimerTimestamp = currentTimer.value();

            if(prevTemp==0.0 || r.temperature < prevTemp) {
                ctx.timerService().deleteProcessingTimeTimer(curTimerTimestamp);
                currentTimer.clear();
            }
            else if(r.temperature > prevTemp && curTimerTimestamp == 0) {
                Long timerTs = ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime() + 1000;
                ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(timerTs);
                currentTimer.update(timerTs);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimer(
                long ts,
                OnTimerContext ctx,
                Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

            out.collect("Temperature of sensor ' " + ctx.getCurrentKey() + " ' monotonically increased for 1 second.");
            currentTimer.clear();

        }
    }

}
```

It should not throw null pointer exception. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with event time in Flink you must arrange for the events to have timestamps, and for the streams to have watermarks. You do this by implementing a timestamp extractor and watermark generator, as described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#timestamp-assigners--watermark-generators) and [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness).

See also [the tutorial](https://training.ververica.com/lessons/event-time-watermarks.html).