# Context in processFunction for KeyedProcessFunction is null

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to use KeyedProcessFunction, but the `ctx: Context` variable in `processFunction` inside my `KeyedProcessFunction` is returning null. Note that I'm using the default `TimeCharacteristic` which is `ProcessingTime` (so I'm not even setting it).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245017/keyedprocessfunction-implementation-throwing-null-pointer-exception) on stackoverflow but that one is relating to EventTime and not ProcessingTime.

Following the exact example of https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#example, I have created the following using Scala 2.11.12 and Flink 1.10, and I'm still getting the same error.

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.{ValueState, ValueStateDescriptor}
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.KeyedProcessFunction
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment


object example {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)

    // the source data stream
    val stream = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999).map(x => {
      var splitCsv = x.stripLineEnd.split(",")
      (splitCsv(0), splitCsv(1))
    }
    )

    // apply the process function onto a keyed stream
    val result: DataStream[Tuple2[String, Long]] = stream
      .keyBy(0)
      .process(new CountWithTimeoutFunction())

    result.print()

    env.execute("Flink Streaming Demo STDOUT")

  }

  /**
   * The data type stored in the state
   */
  case class CountWithTimestamp(key: String, count: Long, lastModified: Long)

  /**
   * The implementation of the ProcessFunction that maintains the count and timeouts
   */
  class CountWithTimeoutFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction[Tuple, (String, String), (String, Long)] {

    /** The state that is maintained by this process function */
    lazy val state: ValueState[CountWithTimestamp] = getRuntimeContext
      .getState(new ValueStateDescriptor[CountWithTimestamp]("myState", classOf[CountWithTimestamp]))


    override def processElement(
                                 value: (String, String),
                                 ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[Tuple, (String, String), (String, Long)]#Context,
                                 out: Collector[(String, Long)]): Unit = {

      // initialize or retrieve/update the state
      val current: CountWithTimestamp = state.value match {
        case null =>
          CountWithTimestamp(value._1, 1, ctx.timestamp)
        case CountWithTimestamp(key, count, lastModified) =>
          CountWithTimestamp(key, count + 1, ctx.timestamp)
      }

      // write the state back
      state.update(current)

      // schedule the next timer 60 seconds from the current event time
      ctx.timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(current.lastModified + 60000)
    }

    override def onTimer(
                          timestamp: Long,
                          ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[Tuple, (String, String), (String, Long)]#OnTimerContext,
                          out: Collector[(String, Long)]): Unit = {

      state.value match {
        case CountWithTimestamp(key, count, lastModified) if (timestamp == lastModified + 60000) =>
          out.collect((key, count))
        case _ =>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   scala.Predef$.Long2long(Predef.scala:363)     at
>   com.leidos.example$CountWithTimeoutFunction.processElement(example.scala:57)
>     at
>   com.leidos.example$CountWithTimeoutFunction.processElement(example.scala:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.KeyedProcessOperator.processElement(KeyedProcessOperator.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(OneInputStreamTask.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(StreamTaskNetworkInput.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:311)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:470)
>     at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)   at
>   org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have something connected to the socket? And are you really using Flink 1.0, or did you mean to say Flink 1.10?

Comment: Meant to say 1.10 hehe
Socket is running. The issue was what Till mentioned below. Thank you David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing in line 57 the `timestamp` field of the `Context`. This field is `null` if you are using `ProcessingTime` or if you don't specify a timestamp extractor when using `EventTime`.

Comment: Ah I see! So the example from Flinks documentation [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#example) is missing valuable information, like using `EventTime` and not assigning the `lastModified` field as a .rowtime?

Comment: One might be able to extend the documentation a bit better. But the JavaDocs of the `Context` class state the behaviour.